# $\log_{x ^ 2 + 1}\sqrt[-x ^ 2 - 4x] {9 - x ^ 2} < 1$

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

I don't know how to solve this inequation.
$$\log_{x ^ 2 + 1}\sqrt[-x ^ 2 - 4x] {9 - x ^ 2} \le 1 \ \text{ so } \ (9 - x ^ 2) ^ {\frac {1} {- x ^ 2  - 4x}} \le x ^ 2 + 1$$

Now, should I have taken the condition $9 - x ^ 2>0$?

OK, so I have asked my teacher about this problem, and, apparently, we must have $-x^2-4x$ natural and, of course, bigger than 1. But it is also smaller than 5, which leaves us with several options for x.  Then we just verify each possible x.

Comment: Yes, you should, as the function won't be defined

Comment: Yes. According to the domain, $x$ should be between $-3$ and $3$.

Comment: Do we also need $-x^2-4x>0$? It feels weird to see something like $\sqrt[-2]{x}$ and we can't have $\sqrt[0]{x}$.

Comment: Well, I don't think we need that condition. And, yes, x can't be 0, since we can't have the base of a logarithm 1 and -4 is out of the domain.